# Running aliases via sudo in bash or ksh

Tags: linux, bash, alias, ksh, sudo

So here is my weirdness from work.

We have user accounts and service accounts and sudo access to the service accounts from the user accounts.  Most, if not all, user accounts are running bash, whilst the service accounts use a misxture of bash or ksh.

When I am logged in as a user(bash) and using sudo to a service account(ksh) and run the following:

`sudo -u svc_user -i alias_name`

The alias runs as expected.

When I am logged in as a user(bash) and using sudo to a service account(bash) and run the following:

`sudo -u svc_user -i alias_name`

I get the error:

`-bash: alias_name: command not found`

Strangely, even when both accounts are bash, I can see the alias:

```
sudo -u svc_user -i alias
alias alias_name='func_name'
sudo -u svc_user -i which alias_name
alias alias_name='func_name'
```

Is there a reason why this works with ksh as the service account shell and not in bash?

Please let me know if any further details are required?

EDIT:- I just want to be clear, the alias I want to run belongs to the service account and not the original user who is calling sudo

Comment: You don't "run" aliases; they are pure text expansion that occurs very early in the processing of a command line. `sudo` expects the name of a file to execute, not arbitrary shell constructs.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the clarification on run versus expands.  Whilst I understand the idea behind the general format of an executable being passed to sudo, it never the less stands that it does execute the alias in ksh and not in bash.  So is there anything I can do to get the same behaviour across both shells?

Answer (score 0):

- Because bash only parse the first word in your command line to check if there is an alias in current environment.
- You can try `sudo alias_name`, maybe also cannot find the alias. But you can try to add `alias sudo='sudo '` to tell bash to parse next command for alias.
- However, for your current case, it maybe actually run command `bash -c xxxx` in your srv_account. So it is not an easy things to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yayong.  Please see my edit as the alias I want to run is inside the .bash_profile of the service account

Comment: Sure, I know your meaning, I meant that maybe actual command run in your service account is "bash -c alias_name", So alias_name still cannot be parsed by bash due to "bash -c" in front of it. You can see the "sudo" user guide for the -i option usages to study the details. Have a nice day.